# Why are the bits reversed?

Tags: c++

In the code bellow, I am trying to store a 2 byte `int` in 2 `char`s. Then, I try to show on the screen the number I stored. Those parts work pretty well.

If I try to see the binary form of the number I stored on the other hand I don't get what I expect. `256` gives me `00000000 1` while the correct is `10000000 0`

```
unsigned int num = 256;
unsigned int pos = 0;

unsigned char a[2] = {num << pos, ((num << pos) & 0xFF00) >> 8};
//we store the number in 2 bytes

cout << (((unsigned int)a[0] + ((unsigned int)a[1] << 8)) >> pos) << endl;
//we check if the number we stored is the num

for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++)//now we display the binary version of the number
{
    for(int j = 0; j < 8; j++)
        cout << ((a[i] >> j)&1);
    cout << " ";
}
```

Can someone please explain what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Your inner `for` loop is going least-significant-bit-first.

Comment: You're doing the wrong math. `256` is `0x 1 0000 0000`

Comment: @user2357112: Is there any other mistake? qwm: I don't understand?

Comment: @Luka: Dunno. Quite likely. I'm not sure what you're trying to do in the initialization of `a` or why you're left-shifting it by 0. It looks like a bug.

Comment: @Luka Ooh, that's what you wanted to understand. You print out bits from lowest to highest, that is why the bits are reversed

Comment: After looking at the code a bit more, your initialization of `a` is also least-significant-byte-first. Combined with the backwards `for` loop, this means you're going through your entire number in reverse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
unsigned char a[2] = {num << pos, ((num << pos) & 0xFF00) >> 8};
```

means that you store the low bits in a[0] and high bits in a[1].

```
256 = 1 00000000
a[0] = 00000000
a[1] = 00000001
```

And `for(int j = 0; j < 8; j++)` ( least significant bits first )should be `for(int j = 7; j >=0; j--)` ( most significant bits first)

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
cout << ((a[i] >> j)&1);
```

To:

```
cout << ((a[i] >> (8-j-1))&1);
```

Or change:

```
for(int j = 0; j < 8; j++)
```

To:

```
for(int j = 8-1; j >= 0; j--)
```

Comment: If I do what you write there I don't get the expected result. I get the correct result if I change the `i` loop to `for(int i = 1; i >= 0; i--)` why does this happen?

Answer (score 1):

Numbers are stored in memory with least significant bits first.

Think of it this way: the number 456 has 6 in the 10^0 place, 5 in 10^1 place, etc. It makes some sense to store it as "654" (where the *i'th* character of the string corresponds to the 10^i'th digit).

The computer stores numbers the same way: the first bit of a number represents the 2^0th place, and the i'th bit to the 2^i'th place.

This rule is actually half-broken with Big Endian, which is a way of storing hexadecimal digits in memory from biggest to smallest (human-readable way).

Comment: This is both not true and not the cause of the problem. There's no well-defined "first bit" of a byte, and both little- and big-endian systems are in widespread use today.

Comment: I've never seen any reference to the MSB as the first bit, so that seems overly pedantic. By what I know as popular convention, the LSB is the first bit. And I explained it this way because I thought the asker had an intuitive idea about the order of bits, which, if reversed, would give the correct result.

Comment: Ah, PowerPC uses MSB 0.